# How to filter a JavaScript Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and predicate function, how do I safely delete all non-matching elements for the map?

---

I could not find an official API function, but I can think of two implementations. The first does not attempt to delete in-place, but instead creates a copy:

```js
// version 1:
function filter(map, pred) {
  const result = new Map();
  for (let [k, v] of map) {
    if (pred(k,v)) {
      result.set(k, v);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const map = new Map().set(1,"one").set(2,"two").set(3,"three");
const even = filter(map, (k,v) => k % 2 === 0);
console.log([...even]); // Output: "[ [ 2, 'two' ] ]"
```

The other deletes in-place. In my tests, it works but I did not find a guarantee that modifying a map does not break the iterator (of the for-of loop):

```js
// version 2:
function deleteIfNot(map, pred) {
  for (let [k, v] of map) {
    if (!pred(k,v)) {
      map.delete(k);
    }
  }
  return map;
}

const map = new Map().set(1,"one").set(2,"two").set(3,"three");
deleteIfNot(map, (k,v) => k % 2 === 0);
console.log([...map]); // Output: "[ [ 2, 'two' ] ]"
```

**Question:**

- Is the second version (the in-place delete) correct on all platforms?
- Is there a better way to implement an in-place filter? Maybe some official API that I missed?

Comment: Working with the array with the functional `filter` means that you will want to modify the clone and return that. Modifying in place is *not* functional (no side effects). If you really want to modify in place, just reassign it to the result of the filterfunction.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

ES6 iterables have no problems when an entry is deleted inside a loop.

There is no special API that would allow to efficiently filter ES6 map entries without iterating over them.

If a map doesn't have to be immutable and should be modified in-place, creating a new map on filtering provides overhead.

There is also Map `forEach`, but it presumes that value will be used, too.

Since the map is being filtered only by its key, there's no use for entry object. It can be improved by iterating over map keys:

```
for (let k of map.keys()) {
  if (!(k % 2))
    map.delete(k);
}
```

Comment: In my real example, pred makes use of the value. But your answer covers all I wanted to know. I was not sure about iterating and at the same time modifying a map. In some other languages (e.g., C++, Java), this will break, or only works if you directly operate on the iterators.

Answer (score 102):

If we want to use **.filter()** iterator for a map, we can apply a simple trick, because there is no .filter operator for ES6 Maps. The approach from [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html) is:

- Convert the map into an array of [key, value] pairs.
- Map or filter the array.
- Convert the result back to a map.

Example:

```js
const map0 = new Map([
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3]
]);

const map1 = new Map(
  [...map0]
  .filter(([k, v]) => v < 3 )
);

console.info([...map1]); 
//[0: ["a", 1], 1: ["b", 2]]
```

Comment: I'm curious what the performance of this is like compared to the accepted answer. Does the intermediate array need to be allocated?

Comment: I am not sure. It is a matter for the testing research.

Comment: @Lukeyb  `[...map0]` and `.filter(...)` are 2 intermediate arrays here. Of course, arrays result in a certain overhead and even more for extra map, this is many times slower than modifying an existing map. But still can be fast enough, performance is not an issue as long as thousands of elements aren't processed per second. Any way, creating a new map is a waste of resources if the case doesn't require an old one to be immutable.

Comment: @Estus_Flask, in my opinion, there is no "intermediate" arrays here.
map0 is given here to show input data structure. So the task is if you have map0 (with this sort of structure), how to filter it and get the result as another map? Of course, if we have as an input an array than we don't need any maps.

Comment: A different way of writing `[...map0]` is `Array.from(map0)`.

Comment: @Peter's comment `Array.from(map)` looks great. It works in Typescript without `--downlevelIteration`.

Comment: Performance of different ways: https://jsbench.me/fjleemuw9s/1. `Array.from(newMap.values()).find` seems to be faster (`[...newMap.values()].find` is slighly slower ocassionally)

Comment: Handy little snippet!

Answer (score 3):

```
// Given a map with keys a, b

const m = new Map()
m.set('a', 1)
m.set('b', 2)

// Return a new map that do not match key a

new Map([...m].filter(([k, v])=>k!=='a'))

// Return a new map only matching value 2

new Map([...m].filter(([k, v])=>v===2))

// Filter in place, removing all values not 2

[...m].map((i)=>i[1]!==2 && m.delete(i[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the immutable Map ([immutable-js.com](https://immutable-js.com/)) library your code will even be one line in combination with the lodash. Basically, as it is written in the official [technical specifications](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v3.8.2/Map/) of the immutable Map, the [filter()](https://immutable-js.com/docs/v3.8.2/Map/#filter()) function does NOT return a mutated Map, but it mutates the source. That is why the source should be cloned first.

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';

_.cloneDeep(Map()).filter(predicate);
```

Here is working example:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import { Map } from 'immutable';

const mixedImmutableMap = Map([[1, 'Some string'], [2, 777], [3, { name: 'User' }], [4, 1234], [5, [1, 2, 3, 4]]]);

describe('Test immutable Map filtering', () => {
  describe('Test filtering map with mixed value types to remove the numbers', () => {
    const result = _.cloneDeep(mixedImmutableMap).filter((value) => !_.isNumber(value));
    it('Should have defined result', () => {
      expect(result).to.be.not.undefined;
    });
    it('Should have result of type immutable Map', () => {
      expect(result instanceof Map).to.be.true;
    });
    it('Should the result not mutate the source', () => {
      expect(result).to.be.not.equal(mixedImmutableMap);
    });
    it('Should actually filter out the map number values', () => {
      expect(result.size).to.be.equal(3);
    });
    console.log(result.toArray());
  });
});
```

Results output:

```
result --> [ 'Some string', { name: 'User' }, [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]


  Test immutable Map filtering
    Test filtering map with mixed value types to remove the numbers
      √ Should have defined result
      √ Should have result of type immutable Map
      √ Should the result not mutate the source
      √ Should actually filter out the map number values


  4 passing (14ms)
```